# fread different behaviour on windows VS Linux

Tags: linux, windows, winapi, fread

I read 8 bytes each time from a file.

the problem is in Windows, when It comes to the last bytes - it finds it less than 8 bytes so fread don't work and returns 0 . so I miss one or more characters from the file.

This behaviour doesn't happen in Linux with the same code.

How can I avoid this ?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164002/why-is-fread-reaching-the-eof-early

Comment: yes, but I still have the same issue

Comment: Show us a minimal example program that demonstrates the bug.

Comment: Try fopen("thefile", "rb") instead of fopen("thefile", "r") and/or post some code that demontrates the problem.